# Bash script to login to server using ssh and run commands

Tags: bash, scripting

Below is the script which i use to create user on server but everytime i need to copy the script on server.I want to create a script which ill run on my machine.ill enter dest IP adddress and hostname in command and script will go to destination server and run commands mentioned in script and user will be created on dest server

```
read -p 'Please Enter The Username To Add: ' name
echo "$name" > /tmp/userlist.txt
clear
echo -e "Hallo $name\nYour Name Is Added To The List."
userfile=/tmp/userlist.txt
username=$(cat /tmp/userlist.txt | tr 'A-Z' 'a-z')
for user in $username
do
sudo useradd $user
sudo passwd $user
done
echo "=================================="

echo "User $name Have Been Created."

echo "=================================="
tail /etc/passwd | cut -d: -f1
```

Answer (score 1):

Nowadays, people are using configuration management or/and a centralized authentication server (Kerberos, LDAP, RADIUS...).

E.g. you can use [Ansible user module](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/user_module.html) to manage users on multiple hosts at once.

Or connect to an Active Directory using Kerberos.

Comment: Hi,we cant use the ansible right now